# Why i am getting 'RTNETLINK answers: No route to host' while adding an IPv6 route?

Tags: networking, routing, iproute

I have the following ipv6 route table:

```
[root@tesla-1 ~]# ip -6 route show
2010:ab7::/64 via 2010:ab7::7 dev pkt0.124  proto static  metric 100
2010:ab7::/64 dev pkt0.124  proto kernel  metric 256
2010:ab8::/64 via 2010:ab8::2 dev pkt0.123  proto static  metric 100
2010:ab8::/64 dev pkt0.123  proto kernel  metric 256
```

but when I try to add following route:

```
[root@tesla-1 ~]# ip -6 route add 2010:ab6::/64 via 2010:ab7::7 dev pkt0.124
RTNETLINK answers: No route to host
```

I am getting `RTNETLINK answers: No route to host` error.

Why I am getting this error?

Also what is the meaning of following line in the `ip -6` route show output:

```
2010:ab7::/64 dev pkt0.124  proto kernel  metric 256
```

Comment: `man ip-route` has the following to say about `proto kernel`: "kernel - the route was installed by the kernel during autoconfiguration." It is a route to the local link that was automatically added when the address was assigned to an interface.

Your routing table looks a bit odd: you have routes to subnets that are reached via a host that is on the same subnet. The via host should be a host that is on *your* subnet that knows how to forward the packets to the non-local subnet in question. What are your local addresses? `(ip -6 addr show`)